# Percentage of notnull value in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to compute the average percentage of not null value in a dataframe:

I try like this :

> df_op.notnull().sum()

but I got a list of each variable with the sum of non null value.

Can you help me to compute the average percentage of non null value which is equal to sum of not null value devided by total num of value.

Thanks

Comment: `df_op.notnull().mean()` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6,np.nan,7]})
print(df)
# average percentage of non null
print(df.val.sum()/len(df.val))
```

Output:

```
   val
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
4  5.0
5  6.0
6  NaN
7  7.0

3.5
```

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to have non-nulls for the complete df, then:

```
notnulls = sum([len(df_op[df_op[col].notnull()]) for col in df_op.columns]) / sum([len(df_op) for col in df_op.columns])
```

If you want non-nulls for each columns:

````
for col in df_op.columns:
    notnulls = len(df_op[df_op[col].notnull()]) / len(df_op)
```
````